# Should i spend on upgrading my Beginner Camera or go for a new Lens instead?

Tags: upgrade

I have a top of the Line (from bottom) Canon 1200D camera, 18-55 stock and 50mm 1.8. I want to spend on a Sigma 18-35 f/1.8 but some of my friends are suggesting to upgrade the camera first instead of going for this lens. Is it worth upgrading my camera first, or just go for a new Sigma ? I can spend upto $700.

I have gone through some questions too like [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/should-i-upgrade-my-camera-or-my-lenses) and [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50792/should-i-upgrade-my-canon-body-or-lens-for-upcoming-travel) but i have a different camera model and I mostly shoot in low light, mostly random shots including portraits and landscapes. (Learning Phase). Thats why i was thinking to go for sigma 18-35 lens but on the other hand better camera body will have higher ISO noise reduction and higher dynamic range.

Comment: Especially the 1200D is pretty poor in low light conditions (1000D and 1100D were even better considering ISO noise), so it might be worth upgrading to a better body first. 
However, you can also make very nice pictures with camera's that are not the very best.

Comment: Check out the measurements at dxomark. Perhaps a better lens won't make any difference. See what the difference in capability of the sensors are, and what kind of shooting you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has a clear cut answer typically, and even more so in your case. You mentioned specifically that you are in the learning phase.

**I wouldn't spend any money, unless it is on books, training, or time!** If you *must* spend money, the Sigma is a fantastic lens, but it isn't going to teach you how to take great photography, you already have everything you need to do that.

I would recommend discussing around friends(or internet sites) that don't encourage gear obsession(worry about DR, high noise ISO etc.) and instead drive you to take more photos and learn!

When your *gear* is what is truly limiting your photographic opportunities, you will have an absolutely clear understanding why and be able to answer this question yourself if necessary. Now is not the time. Go take some photos!

Comment: Have you considered posting this as an answer to the duplicate? It's probably the right answer to the "what should I buy next" question.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - On that duplicate I added a comment about two years ago with the same basic idea, but not as an answer. I'll add one! Thanks.

Comment: Thats the answer to my question, Im going out to take photos :)